How do I connect an lnd docker image to my umbrel bitcoin node?
I have an umbrel node running a full bitcoin node as an app. I would like to run a lnd docker image  (https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/DOCKER.md) on my laptop and connect to it (using it to sync with the blockchain). But I cannot find any instruction on how to actually docker run the lightning container, let alone how to connect it to my umbrel node. It always complains its missing rfc configs but there is no documentation on how to set this up.
So basically, umbrel node runs on the network, the lightning container should run on my laptop. I want to do transactions from my laptop using lncli (or the rest api). How do I start the docker container right so it connects to umbrel and lets me run transactions?
